# Visual Studio Intellisense shows "new expression can be simplified", but that fails the build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.6.1

I have this code

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
```

VS Intellisense shows:

> 'new' expression can be simplified

and upon selecting that action, it changes the code to:

```
MyClass instance = new();
```

but then build fails with error code CS8181:

> 'new' cannot be used with tuple type. Use a tuple literal expression instead.

I am unable to understand this error message as `MyClass` is not related to `tuple` type. It's a plain class with `int`, `string` and `list` properties and no inheritance. Also, why should an Intellisense suggested action cause an error.

I've reported this issue to VS Dev Community. [Link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Intellisense-suggesting-code-improvement/1603447)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "Why should an Intellisense suggested action cause an error" - why should any program malfunction? Report it as a bug.

Comment: @Llama But even if Intellisense has a bug, I can't report it unless I understand the build error. Error is not making sense to me.

Comment: Why? It seems reasonable to me. "This is my class. Here is my code that Intellisense prompts me to refactor. When I do, the code becomes like this and I get a compilation error which is this."

Comment: You can send Microsoft a video of you reproducing the problem , plus all the code etc. Use the Vs "report a problem" option. Perhaps, too, `var instance = new MyClass();` will make the suggestion go away ..

Comment: *"'new' cannot be used with tuple type. Use a tuple literal expression instead."* - Show the actual line where it makes the suggestion and applying it causes the build to fail. You haven't shown anything related to tuple types even though the error message explicitly mentions them.

Comment: @madreflection The error is exactly on the same line. There's no tuple related to this class, as I have already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks all. I will report the issue to MS.

Comment: Wait, you've tagged .NET 4.6.1. What language version do you have selected? `new()` is C# 9.0 but it's not supported on older platforms, although certain features, like this, don't require framework support. Make sure you include that fact in the bug report. It shouldn't suggest the change for older language versions.

Comment: @madreflection Yes, target-typed new() is only supported in C# 9.0, which one doesn't normally use with .NET4.6 (although it is possible to some degree). However, I still consider it an intelisense bug to suggest a change that is not valid for the current language version.

Comment: @PMF: Agreed. That's why I told OP to include that in the bug report.

Answer (score 5):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0090) this available if you use C#9.0+. I guess that you use lower version of C# than required.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).